# Are there plans for a progress indicator?

Tags: nautilus, indicator, ayatana

Status menus seem to be intended, among other things, to streamline indications. Some of these indications are not confined to the old Notification Area: others can be found on their own windows and indicate running processes, such as Nautilus copying some files, Firefox performing downloads or Brasero burning a DVD.

I have seen [a series of mockups](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Ayatana/ProgressIndication) showcasing mockups for a progress indicator:

[image]

[image]

I would like to know if there are any actual plans to create a real progress indicator to house this type of indications.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It IS possible via library called Taskview. See https://github.com/ssickert/TaskView. It already has plugins for lots of apps, we just need an AppIndicator which supports it.

Answer (score 1):

it won't happen with the current notification service... there are replacement notification services that could/would support such a thing, but the current dbus notification can't hack such a thing.